# Dynamic Column Alias Creation & Joining

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to query some data in snowflake and save myself a bunch of hard-coding

My data rows (let's call this subquery `A`) look something like this

```
| my_index  | score | some_enum |
|-----------|-------|-----------|
| abc.      | 100.  | x.        |
| abc.      | 50.   | x.        |
| abc.      | 50.   | y.        |
| abc.      | 60.   | y.        |
| def.      | 90.   | z.        |
```

I want to group by `my_index` and `test_name`, compute average scores, and then join all of this data back together with dynamic column names based on `some_enum`, so it would look something like

```
| my_index  | avg_score_x | avg_score_y | avg_score_z | avg_score |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-----------|
| abc.      | 75.         | 55.         | 0/NaN/-1.   | 65.       |
| def.      | 0/NaN/-1.   | 0/NaN/-1.   | 90.         | 90.       |
```

Does anybody have a clean way of dynamically creating these column names and joining this data?

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    myindex,
    avg(case when some_enum = 'x' then score end) avg_score_x,
    avg(case when some_enum = 'y' then score end) avg_score_y,
    avg(case when some_enum = 'z' then score end) avg_score_z,
    avg(score) avg_score
from a
group by myindex
order by myindex
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful – I have a bunch of columns though (imagine `avg_score`, `score_variance`, `median_score`, etc), so while I definitely could write it all out for my enums, it would be a bit messy. Is there a way to join everything back together but with dynamic column names based on the value of `some_enum`?

Comment: @mjkaufer: this requires dynamic SQL, ie build a query string, then execute it. This is really another beast.

Comment: There's also a built in PIVOT.  But it too required dynamic sql.